# Is there a published standard for the sectioning of math papers?

Tags: article-writing

Most papers seem to use sections (e.g. 3) and sub-sections (e.g. 3.1). Is there a published standard that says what sort of thing warrants its own section and what sort of thing warrants its own sub-section?

Comment: @Surb I'll edit the question

Comment: Read other papers and see what they do.  Then do it in a way that seems natural to you.

Comment: Actually each journal has its own separate standard.  Some use section numbers and some just have section titles without numbers. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't mean to ask about the numbering, but rather how mathematicians section their papers

Comment: @GEdgar That's actually why I'm asking. I've only ever sectioned one paper (for class, not published) in a way that I've been happy with, and that seemed to be an accident.

Comment: How it's done?  Just common sense, I think. ${}\qquad{}$